# C++ Python - One way Synchronizes two folders

Tags: python

I Have a Taks and have 2 problems from this steps:

1.cant write in log file, because writing only one line, first step of loop.

2.cant update time of action-> print("Last time updated at: =", CurrentData) //one problem is here, not updating time in loop

Please implement a program that synchronizes two folders: source and replica. The
program should maintain a full, identical copy of source folder at replica folder.
Solve the test task by writing a program in one of these programming languages:

Python
C++

Synchronization must be one-way: after the synchronization content of the
replica folder should be modified to exactly match content of the source
folder;

Synchronization should be performed periodically.
File creation/copying/removal operations should be logged to a file and to the
console output;

on this defend my life!

```
import os
import shutil
from time import time, sleep
from datetime import datetime




print('Synchronization will be done every 10 seconds')


#here we ask location of file from where we want to copy files.
print('Please write Location of main Folder, Example:D:\FolderOne\\')
source_folder=input('')

#here we ask location of folder where we want to paste files.
print('Please write Location of replica Folder, Example:D:\FolderTwo\\')
#destination_folder=input('')

now = datetime.now()
CurrentData= now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

while True:
    for file_name in os.listdir(source_folder):

        source = source_folder + file_name
        destination = destination_folder + file_name

        if os.path.isfile(source):
            shutil.copy(source, destination)
            print('File ', file_name, ' has moved from: ',source_folder, ' to: ',destination_folder)
            f = open("D:\log.txt", "w")
            writingText='File '+file_name+' has moved from: '+source_folder+' to: '+destination_folder+CurrentData
            f.write(writingText)
            //Second problem is here, cant write in log.txt file full loop information

    

    print("Last time updated at: =", CurrentData) //one problem is here, not updating time in loop
    sleep(60 - time() % 60)
    os.system('cls')
```

Comment: you can use module `watchdog` to monitor event generated in the source based on that you can perform action and replicated in destination.
https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of the program you can copy all content of source to destination , later now you can use module `watchdog` to monitor event generated in the source and take action based on the event (you can also log this event to log file), so you don't have copy all content from source every time.

https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/